# Summing column values in panda and attaching or merging total to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I got this function :

```
def source_revenue(self):
    items = self.data.items()
    df = pandas.DataFrame(
        {'SOURCE OF BUSINESS': [i[0] for i in items], 'INCOME': [i[1] for i in items]})
    pivoting = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['SOURCE OF BUSINESS'], values=['INCOME'])
    suming = pivoting.sum(index=(0), columns=(1))
```

This function yields this :

```
INCOME    216424.9
dtype: float64
```

Without summing, it returns the full dataframe like this :

```
                               INCOME
SOURCE OF BUSINESS                    
BYD - Other                      500.0
BYD - Retail                    1584.0
BYD - Transport                42498.0
BYD Beverage - A La Carte      39401.5
BYD Food - A La Carte 瓦厂食品－零点  68365.0
BYD Food - Catering Banquet    53796.0
BYD Rooms 瓦厂房间                  5148.0
GS - Retail                      386.0
GS Food - A La Carte              48.0
Orchard Retail                   130.0
SCH - Food - A La Carte           96.0
SCH - Retail                     375.4
SCH - Transport                  888.0
SCH Beverage - A La Carte        119.0
Spa                             3052.0
XLM Beverage - A La Carte         38.0
```

The reason I am doing this is because I was trying to get the total of all the returned rows, sum them and attach a total to the dataframe.

Initially I tried with margins = True (I read around here that it was to sum and attach the total to the dataframe, not true )

So what I want to know if there is a way to return the dataframe, but also sum up the values and attach a total to the end of the dataframe just as `margins = True` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use rather [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) as [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html), because here `groupby` is faster.

You can use `pivot_table`, but default `aggfunc` is `np.mean`. It is easy forget for it:

```
pivoting = pd.pivot_table(df, 
                          index=['SOURCE OF BUSINESS'], 
                          values=['INCOME'], 
                          aggfunc=np.mean)
```

I think you need `aggfunc=np.sum`:

```
print df
     A    B      C  D
0  zoo  one  small  1
1  zoo  one  large  2
2  zoo  one  large  2
3  foo  two  small  3
4  foo  two  small  3
5  bar  one  large  4
6  bar  one  small  5
7  bar  two  small  6
8  bar  two  large  7

print pd.pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A'], aggfunc=np.sum)
A
bar    22
foo     6
zoo     5
Name: D, dtype: int64

df1 = df.groupby('A')['D'].sum()
print df1
A
bar    22
foo     6
zoo     5
Name: D, dtype: int64
```

If you need add `Total` to Series, use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html) and [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
print df1.sum()
33

df1.loc['Total'] = df1.sum()
print df1
A
bar      22
foo       6
zoo       5
Total    33
Name: D, dtype: int64
```

**Timings**:

```
In [111]: %timeit df.groupby('A')['D'].sum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 581 µs per loop

In [112]: %timeit pd.pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A'], aggfunc=np.sum)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.28 ms per loop
```

Adding `Total` in your `df` by [setting with enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement):

```
print df
                              INCOME
SOURCE OF BUSINESS                  
BYD - Other                    500.0
BYD - Retail                  1584.0
BYD - Transport              42498.0
BYD Beverage - A La Carte    39401.5
BYD Food - A La Carte        68365.0
BYD Food - Catering Banquet  53796.0
BYD Rooms                     5148.0
GS - Retail                    386.0
GS Food - A La Carte            48.0
Orchard Retail                 130.0
SCH - Food - A La Carte         96.0
SCH - Retail                   375.4
SCH - Transport                888.0
SCH Beverage - A La Carte      119.0
Spa                           3052.0
XLM Beverage - A La Carte       38.0
```

```
df.loc['Total', 'INCOME'] = df['INCOME'].sum()
print df
                               INCOME
SOURCE OF BUSINESS                   
BYD - Other                     500.0
BYD - Retail                   1584.0
BYD - Transport               42498.0
BYD Beverage - A La Carte     39401.5
BYD Food - A La Carte         68365.0
BYD Food - Catering Banquet   53796.0
BYD Rooms                      5148.0
GS - Retail                     386.0
GS Food - A La Carte             48.0
Orchard Retail                  130.0
SCH - Food - A La Carte          96.0
SCH - Retail                    375.4
SCH - Transport                 888.0
SCH Beverage - A La Carte       119.0
Spa                            3052.0
XLM Beverage - A La Carte        38.0
Total                        216424.9
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer and the perf tests. I am getting ```NameError: name 'np' is not defined``` when trying to implement np.sum ... probably a missing import ?

Comment: Ok done, I had to import ```numpy``` and the actual attr is ```numpy.sum```

Comment: If you use `import numpy as np`, you can use `np.sum`.

Answer (score 1):

`df.ix[len(df)] = ...` will add a row to the end of your dataframe.  Your data then needs to match the correct number of columns.  Also, I wouldn't recommend adding this to your data as any subsequent analysis would be invalid.  Probably best to create a new series and then concat if needed for display purposes.

```
df.ix[len(df)] = ['Total', df.INCOME.sum()]

>>> df
                 SOURCE OF BUSINESS   INCOME
0                       BYD - Other      500
1                      BYD - Retail     1584
2                   BYD - Transport    42498
3         BYD Beverage - A La Carte  39401.5
4   BYD Food - A La Carte _______      68365
5       BYD Food - Catering Banquet    53796
6                    BYD Rooms ____     5148
7                       GS - Retail      386
8              GS Food - A La Carte       48
9                    Orchard Retail      130
10          SCH - Food - A La Carte       96
11                     SCH - Retail    375.4
12                  SCH - Transport      888
13        SCH Beverage - A La Carte      119
14                              Spa     3052
15        XLM Beverage - A La Carte       38
16                            Total   216425
```